# get value from HTML input using JS

Tags: javascript, html, oop

I just started learning coding. and i was trying to apply the OOP pradigm to an example.
I am trying to create an object (the character here) and assign its properties as the values input within the html file.

the error that keeps appearing is 'javascript.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') .

```
    <body>
    <label for="namebox">Character Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="namebox">
    <label for="agebox">Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="agebox">
    <label for="humanclass">Human</label>
    <label for="majinclass">Majin</label>

    <input type="radio" name="class1" id="humanclass">
    <input type="radio" name="class1" id="majinclass">

    <input type="button" value="Create Character" id="creationbtn" onclick='char1.identify()'>
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel">

</body>
```

```
    class Charcreation {
    constructor(name, age, charclass) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.class = charclass;
    }

    identify() {
        console.log('my name is ' + this.name + ' and i am a ' + this.age + ' years old ' + this.class)
    }
}


charname = document.getElementById("namebox").value;
charage = document.getElementById('agebox').value;
charselection = document.getElementByName('class1').value;
charclass =
    function getClass() {
        for (i == 0; i < charselection.length; i++) {
            if (charselection[i].checked)
                return charselection[i];
        }
    }

char1 = new Charcreation(charname, charage, charclass())
char1.identify();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `getElementsByName` not `getElementByName`

Comment: It occurs because of  radio button value property is missing

Comment: your loop is also wrong it should look like this `for (let i = 0; i < charselection.length; i++) {` but the other problem is this `charselection = document.getElementsByName("class1").value;` remove the `.value` just get the element

Comment: What - line does it say the error is on? Always useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code as @Chris G points out plus some others. Here's an update to your code with corrections to get a successful output for your `char1.identify();` method.

I've added some CSS styling that's not necessary to the output.

When the user clicks on the `#creationbtn` button, code execution needs to retrieve values of the form controls each time. Your original code is retrieving values of the `input` controls when the page is loaded and not each time the button is clicked.

```js
class Charcreation {
  constructor(name, age, charclass) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.class = charclass;
  }

  identify() {
    var identityText = 'my name is ' + this.name + ' and i am a ' + this.age + ' years old ' + this.class;
    //console.log(identityText);
    document.querySelector("#identity").textContent = identityText;
  }
}

function createIdentity() {
  var charname = document.getElementById("namebox").value;
  var charage = document.getElementById('agebox').value;
  var charselection = document.getElementsByName('class1');
  var charclass =
    function getClass() {
      for (i = 0; i < charselection.length; i++) {
        if (charselection[i].checked) {
          var labelElem = document.querySelector("label[for=" + charselection[i].id + "]");
          if (labelElem) {
            return labelElem.textContent;
          }
        }
      }
    }

  var char1 = new Charcreation(charname, charage, charclass());
  char1.identify();
}
```

```css
#character-form {
  display: grid;
  width: 15rem;
}

.radio-control {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  padding: .5rem 0;
  width: fit-content;
}

.radio-control input {
  margin: 0 .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="character-form">
  <label for="namebox">Character Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="" id="namebox">

  <label for="agebox">Age</label>
  <input type="text" name="" id="agebox">

  <span class="radio-control">
        <label for="humanclass">Human</label>
        <input type="radio" name="class1" id="humanclass">
    </span>
  <span class="radio-control">
        <label for="majinclass">Majin</label>
        <input type="radio" name="class1" id="majinclass">
    </span>

  <input type="button" value="Create Character" id="creationbtn" onclick='createIdentity()'>
  <input type="reset" value="Cancel">
  <span id="identity"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate everybody's help. as dave said my code was retrieving data as soon as the page load. It was very educational. Not gonna lie, i don't know this 'document.querySelector' but its my turn now to search it up. Thanks for the extra CSS

Comment: @Gilga74 This post provides a good overview of all DOM search methods, including `document.querySelector`: https://javascript.info/searching-elements-dom

Answer (score 0):

> the error that keeps appearing is 'javascript.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') .

Have you made sure that the script is firing after the DOM gets rendered?
It's possible that it is running before the actual HTML has been rendered and that is why `.getElementById("namebox")` is returning null.

There are probably other ways to ensure this, but the easiest I know of is just put the script inside of the footer instead of the header.